# Input not supported

Tags: laptop, display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I connected my HDMI laptop with a VGA monitor and It said input not supported. I choose 'show display only at 2 ' and now is everything black my monitor and my laptop. In my other laptop I managed to connect the monito but now I want to know how can I see my first laptops screen even if I connect it to my monitor so I can change the settings to use my monitor.

Comment: Remember we cannot see over your shoulder so you need to describe things to us in terms we can understand without being there.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Windows + P, you'll see how your screen is projected right now and find the PC only screen. After that you can plug back you monitor and do the same thing without actually seeing what you're doing.

It worked for me!